# Capture selected option returns not defined instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to capture the selected user option and send that value in a post request.

Let's ignore the post part as it is not directly related to the question.

But right now the value appears as undefined.

**CodePen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/yLyQQaP

I've this JS, but `lista_id`, the value I need to capture, appears as `undifined`. Why?

> I've tried to set this as a global variable. In the JS, you'll see an
>   alert, this alerts undefined for `lista_id`

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $("#agregarProducto1").click(function () {
    var lista_id;
    $('#listas-de-usuario').change(function() {
       var lista_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    });
    alert(lista_id);
    // $.post("{% url 'listas/agregar-producto/", {
    //     c_slug: "cuadernos",
    //     s_slug: "Cuadernos",
    //     product_slug: "cuadernos-rojos",
    //     lista_id: lista_id,
    //    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the variable only once either globally or in the surrounding function and then not declare them inside the `click` or `change` handlers. This way, it is the same variable you are referring to.

Also, the code to bind `change` handler could be outside the `click` handler, otherwise it would be bound every time the button is clicked.

Example of global variable declaration:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cpshah/pen/zYxMywY)

Example of variable declared inside `document ready` function of jQuery:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cpshah/pen/MWYzZmR)